# upgrading from Redis 2.8.19 to 3.0.1

Tags: redis

I currently have installed Redis 2.8.19 but I'm looking to upgrade to the latest stable release 3.0.1.  Originally I downloaded, uncompressed, and compiled 2.8.9.  What is the recommended approach to upgrade from 2.8.19 to 3.0.1 if you have previously compiled it like I have?  I've tried to find resources on this but coming up short.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should accept some answer if it fits. http://serverfault.com/a/706748/213996 is good and is from the redis' author, so it's pretty reliable.

Answer (score 9):

just download Redis 3.0.3 (not 3.0.1! Is already old) and compile as usually with `make`, and then use `make install`. Make sure that the old binary is replaced by the new one, so check where your current Redis binary is.

Redis 3.0.3 is mostly backward compatible with Redis 2.8.x (I would say 99.999%). The only few differences are listed in the Changelog file.

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove old version redis

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get remove redis-server
   ```
2. Install new version(for example version 3.2.8) via make:

   ```
   $ wget http://download.redis.io/releases/redis-3.2.8.tar.gz

   $ tar xzf redis-3.2.8.tar.gz

   $ cd redis-3.2.8

   $ make
   ```
3. Run redis:

   ```
   $ src/redis-server
   ```